# Reading "Awkward" CSV Files with FSharp CsvParser

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have a large file (200K - 300K lines of text).
It's almost but not quite a CSV file.

1. The column headers are on the second row, there's a row of dummy text
   before that.
2. There are rows interspersed with the actual data rows. They have 
   commas, but most of the columns are blank. They aren't relevant to me.

I need to read this file efficiently, and parse the lines that actually are
valid, as CSV data.

My first idea was to write a clean procedure that strips out the first line, and the blank lines, leaving only the headers and details that I want
in a CSV File that the CsvParser can read.

This is easy enough, just ReadLine from a StreamReader, I can keep or disregard each line just by looking at it as a string.

Now though I have a new issue.

There is a column in the valid data that I can use to disregard a whole lot more rows.

If I read the Cleaned file using the CsvParser it's easy to filter by that column.

But, I don't really want to waste writing the rows I don't need to the Clean file.

I'd like to be able to check that Column, while Cleaning the File. But, at that point I'm working with strings representing entire lines. It's not easy to get at the specific column I want.

I can't Split on ',' there may be commas in the text of other columns.
I'm ending up writing the Csv Parsing Logic, that I was using CsvParser for in the first place.

Ideally, I'd like to read in the existing file, clean out the lines that I can based on strings, then somehow parse the resulting seq using the CsvParser.

I see CsvFile can Load from Streams and Readers, but I'm not sure that's much help.

Any suggestions or am I just asking too much? Should I just deal with the extra filtering on loading the Cleaned File?

Comment: FYI, in the absence of any better Ideas, I'm writing initially to a Temp File that has the badly formed rows removed. Then using the CsvParser to Filter the other rows and write to the actual Clean File.

Comment: It'd be easier for us to help if you show us what the file looks like. Not all 200k lines, but enough to capture the essence of the problem. From the description, I think it would be doable in fewer than 10 lines.

Comment: It would be best to see a sample even with a link to a gist. I think your initial solution with the tmp file makes sense. Another two methods you can explore is to specify the schema of the csv file and use the ignore errors options; or use another .net csv parser like FileHelpers.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid doing most of the work of parsing by using the `CsvFile` class directly.

The [F# Data documentation](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html) has some extended examples that show how to do this in some detail.

Skipping over lines at the start of a file is handled by the `skipRows` parameter. Passing the `ignoreErrors` parameter will also ignore rows that fail to parse.

```
open FSharp.Data
let csv = CsvFile.Load(file, skipRows=1, ignoreErrors=true)
for row in csv.Rows do
    printfn "%s" row.GetColumn "Name"
```

If you have to do more complex filtering of rows, a simple approach that doesn't require temporary files is to filter the results of `File.ReadLines` and pass that to `CsvFile.Parse`.

The example below skips a six-line prelude, reads in lines until it hits a blank line, uses `CsvFile` to parse the data, and finally filters the resulting rows to those of interest.

```
let tableA =
    File.ReadLines(file)
    |> Seq.skip(6) 
    |> Seq.takeWhile(fun l -> String.length l > 0) 
    |> String.concat "\n"

let csv = CsvFile.Parse(tableA)
for row in csv.Rows.Filter(fun row -> row?Close.AsFloat() > row?Open.AsFloat()) do
    printfn "%s" row.GetColumn "Name"
```